# How can I get Magento 2x admin path url in custom extension controller

Tags: magento2

Is this possible to get admin path url in custom module controller? How can I get for Magento 2x? there I don't have default admin in path.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Technologymindz. All rights reserved.
 */

namespace Technologymindz\Instagramfeed\Controller\Adminhtml\Insta;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Auth extends \Technologymindz\Instagramfeed\Controller\Adminhtml\Insta
{
   public function __construct(
        //other stuff you need here
        \Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig\Reader $configReader
    ) {
        $this->configReader = $configReader;
        //other stuff you need here, like parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    /**
     * Items list.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {

                $config = $this->configReader->load();
                $adminSuffix = $config['backend']['frontName'];
        echo   $adminUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl() . $adminSuffix;
        die;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
public function __construct(
        //other stuff you need here
        \Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig\Reader $configReader
    ) {
        $this->configReader = $configReader;
        //other stuff you need here, like parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
```

Use below line to get admin url:

```
$config = $this->configReader->load();
$adminSuffix = $config['backend']['frontName'];
$adminUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl() . $adminSuffix;
```

Comment: This give me error: Fatal error: Call to a member function isLoggedIn() on null in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php on line 252  what about this?

Comment: Put your full code in your question

Comment: check the update, i have added your code in that too

Comment: this error is not from this file may be its coming from other code so please make sure

Comment: i did check before use this code all is working to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the admin URL by making use of the helper class,  `\Magento\Backend\Helper\Data`

Change your controller file like the following,

```
<?php 
namespace Technologymindz\Instagramfeed\Controller\Adminhtml\Insta;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Auth extends \Technologymindz\Instagramfeed\Controller\Adminhtml\Insta
{

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig\Reader $configReader,
\Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $HelperBackend )
{
    $this->configReader = $configReader;
    $this->HelperBackend = $HelperBackend;
    //other stuff you need here, like parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

 public function execute()
 {
    echo $this->HelperBackend->getHomePageUrl();
    die;
 }
}
```

Run the setup upgrade command and check the result.